# How to debug token positions in petri nets in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-pic

Following an example given in [How to make this TikZ picture more idiomatic? (environment diagram)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/515909/how-to-make-this-tikz-picture-more-idiomatic-environment-diagram)

I tried to use the pre-defined "pic" to place more "function definition icons" on the canvas using relative positioning ( `right=of` and `base right=of`). However, there is a slight displacement of the petri net tokens inside the two rounded nodes.

Although it is probably possible to replace the tokens with tiny filled nodes themselves, still, is there a way to debug token positioning in TikZ-petri nets?

The "almost minimal" example follows.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,petri,arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0mm,>=stealth',very thick,color=black!50,
     font=\sffamily,pics/two dots/.style={code={
     \node [draw,minimum size=5mm,circle,colored tokens={black!50}] 
     (#1-left) {};
    \node [draw,minimum size=5mm,circle,colored tokens={black!50},
    right=0pt of #1-left]
        (#1-right) {};
    \node [rectangle, fit=(#1-left) (#1-right)] (#1){};
    \node [circle,fill=red,minimum size=1mm] at (#1-left) {};
    \node [circle,fill=red,minimum size=1mm] at (#1-right) {};
     }},
    every pin edge/.style={<-,very thick},
   box/.style={draw,rectangle,inner sep=#1},box/.default=2mm]

  \node (W1)   {factorial:};
  \node (fake1) [right=190mm of W1] {};  
  \node (fact-iter) [above=1mm of W1] {fact-iter:};
%
  \node (g env) [box, fit=(W1) (fake1) (fact-iter),
  pin={[text width=1cm,pin distance=10mm]left:global env}]
  { };
  % factorial
  \path ([yshift=-20mm]W1.east)pic{two dots=w1fun}
    (w1fun) edge [<-, to path={|- (\tikztotarget)}] (W1.east);
  \node [below=of w1fun-left, align=left] {\ttfamily parameters: n \\ body: \dots}
    edge [<-] (w1fun-left.center); 
  \draw[->] (w1fun-right.center) -| ([xshift=3mm] w1fun-right.east |- g env.south);

  % fact-iter
  \path pic[base right=20mm of w1fun.east]{two dots=fact-iter-fun}
    (fact-iter-fun) edge [<-, to path={|- (\tikztotarget)}] (fact-iter.east);
  \node [below=of fact-iter-fun-left, align=left] {\ttfamily parameters: todo \\ body: \dots}
    edge [<-] (fact-iter-fun-left.center); 
  \draw[->] (fact-iter-fun-right.center) -| ([xshift=3mm] fact-iter-fun-right.east |- g env.south);


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Update: I added tiny debug nodes in order to understand positioning, and I am not amused. The centres of the circles, tokens and debug nodes seem to all be different. What to do?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `positioning` techniques of the library of the same name do unfortunately not work for pics. The pgf key that you want to apply to the pic in fact gets applied to the nodes in such a way that they want to use their left west anchor for the positioning, hence the additional shift. But in your case there is a very simple fix: introduce an auxiliary coordinate that you use for positioning.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,petri,arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0mm,>=stealth',very thick,color=black!50,
     font=\sffamily,pics/two dots/.style={code={
     \node [draw,minimum size=5mm,circle,colored tokens={black!50}] 
     (#1-left) {};
    \node [draw,minimum size=5mm,circle,colored tokens={black!50},
    right=0pt of #1-left]
        (#1-right) {};
    \node [rectangle, fit=(#1-left) (#1-right)] (#1){};
    }},
    every pin edge/.style={<-,very thick},
   box/.style={draw,rectangle,inner sep=#1},box/.default=2mm]

  \node (W1)   {factorial:};
  \node (fake1) [right=190mm of W1] {};  
  \node (fact-iter) [above=1mm of W1] {fact-iter:};
%
  \node (g env) [box, fit=(W1) (fake1) (fact-iter),
  pin={[text width=1cm,pin distance=10mm]left:global env}]
  { };
  % factorial
  \path ([yshift=-20mm]W1.east)pic{two dots=w1fun}
    (w1fun) edge [<-, to path={|- (\tikztotarget)}] (W1.east);
  \node [below=of w1fun-left, align=left,draw=red, rectangle, very thin] {parameters: d \\ body: \dots}
    edge [<-] (w1fun-left.center); 
  \draw[->] (w1fun-right.center) -| ([xshift=3mm] w1fun-right.east |- g env.south);

  % fact-iter
  \path coordinate[base right=15mm of w1fun.east] (aux)
  (aux)  pic{two dots=fact-iter-fun}
    (fact-iter-fun) edge [<-, to path={|- (\tikztotarget)}] (fact-iter.east);
  \node [below=of fact-iter-fun-left, align=left,draw=red, very thin,rectangle] {parameters: todo \\ body: \dots}
    edge [<-] (fact-iter-fun-left.center); 
  \draw[->] (fact-iter-fun-right.center) -| ([xshift=3mm] fact-iter-fun-right.east |- g env.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You may have to increase the distance.